# Paypal Core Dotnet SDK

Tags: asp.net, paypal, nuget-package

Where can I find the documentation or some details how can to use the nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPalCoreSDK/

Answer (score 0):

You would typically not use the PayPalCoreSDK dll directly but use one of PayPal's API SDKs listed [here](http://paypal.github.io/. These SDKs in turn depend on PayPalCoreSDK.

You can refer to the samples available with each SDK at https://github.com/search?q=%40paypal+dotnet to understand how each of the SDKs can be used.